# Slicing up a cake with a verse written on it

Tags: tanach, food, shemos-sacred-names, text, genizah-storage

Is it allowed to write a verse on a cake or slice such cake up? In your answer please bring sources!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the oldest source we have for this custom is from the [Rokeach, siman 196](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21522&pgnum=193):

> "It is our forefathers' custom to sit the children to study during Shavuot...and afterwards they bring a cake rolled in honey and upon it is written the verses "My Sovereign  GOD gave me a skilled tongue, to know how to speak timely words to the weary. Morning by morning, [God] rouses me, rousing my ear to give heed like disciples. My Sovereign GOD opened my ears and I did not disobey, I did not run away." ([Yeshayahu 50:4-5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.50.4-5?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))...and they feed the child the cake..."

According to [Din Online](https://din.org.il/2019/05/22/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%92%D7%94/), although there is the issue of erasing verses, there is that ancient minhag of preparing cakes with verses for new students on the day they start learning Torah (parallel minhagim include smearing honey on a chumash or Torah scroll or giving candy), so there's room for leniency in cutting up and eating verses on such cakes.

The rabbi who wrote the answer noted, however, that the Yaavetz thought that this custom was problematic and should not be followed.

[Migdal Oz, Brechot Ha'Mayim, Brechat Giv'on, Te'alah Alef](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30778&pgnum=14) states:

> "...ואף אם מנהג אכילת העוגה שכתובים עליה פסוקים ושמות, יש להרהר אחריו, והיכא דנהוג נהוג..."
>
> "...and even if the custom of eating a cake upon which are written verses and Names, one must rethink this, and where this custom is followed, it is as it is..."

As such, the rabbi concluded that if there's room for leniency if the cake was made for a special Torah-related occasion, but for other occasions, other treats are preferable. Rabbi Shalom Siani also [wrote](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=61632&st=&pgnum=79) that it's preferable not to write the customary verses on the child's cake and instead to write them on a piece of paper and place them upon the cake.

Rabbi Oshri Azulai, on the other hand, [wrote](https://kavhalacha.co.il/%D7%90%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/2017-05-30-05-42-106) in the name of Rabbi Elyashiv, Rabbi Kanievsky, and Rabbi Auerbach: Although there is the issue raised by the Yaavetz, as it was written from the onset on foodstuff, the verse has no holiness and therefore may be consumed (brought by Rabbi Yechezkel Finehandler in [Ginzei Hakodesh, p. 138, n. 30](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53650&pgnum=138)). Rabbi Azulai concluded that eating such a case under any circumstance would be allowed, but being stricter here (i.e., avoiding eating verses) is recommended.